# How to performance test analysis services

Tags: jmeter, azure-analysis-services

How can I write a performance test using JMeter against analysis services?

I've seen this post regarding the usage of Java libraries but I'm using .NET (classic) C#.

https://superuser.com/questions/1398297/jmeter-connection-with-ssas-cubes-sql-server-analysis-services/1399109#1399109

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java libraries for connecting to OLAP services are not for the application under test, they are **for JMeter**.

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, **a 100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance.

So the answer is still applicable given your application uses [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)

Check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter/) article which should help you to get started to use Java/Groovy code and they add OLAP libraries to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and implement your logic using them.